# Extract the Id's number of multiple elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have this simple code:

```js
$('[id^=pz]').change(function() {

  //Getting the numbers after the letters "pz":
  //1
  //2
  //100

});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="pz1">
<input type="text" id="pz2">
<input type="text" id="pz100">
```

How to retrieve the number of each element?

Thanks.

Comment: `var num = this.id.substr(2);`!

Comment: thank you very much @ibrahim mahrir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Use **`Array#match`** with simple `RegExp`.

Click on any input to reveal it's number.

```js
$('input').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id').match(/(?!pz)\d+/g)[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pz1">
<input type="text" id="pz2">
<input type="text" id="pz100">
<input type="text" id="pwadawdz7">
<input type="text" id="random98">
```

Comment: lol :) Yes you're right, your answer is one of the best , you really deserve that,

Comment: *"I really care about your future as developer, that's why I suggest you to use my code instead"* That is a good joke, thanks for the laugh.

Comment: I down voted it because of that comments begging to get picked. Your solution is nothing better than the others that use a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `match` function:

```
var m = $(this).attr('id').match("pz([0-9]+)"); // m = ["pz1", "1"]
var num = m[1];
```

`match` takes a regex and returns the input matching the regex as well as possible capturing groups (i.e. the things matching the parts in parentheses).

Note: in latest jQuery, use `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this ;)

```js
$('[id^=pz]').change(function(event) {

// with substr must have 2 chars
var id = event.target.id.substr(2);
console.log('substr', id)

// with regexp
var id2 = event.target.id.match('[0-9]+')[0];
console.log('regexp', id2)


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="pz1">
<input type="text" id="pz2">
<input type="text" id="pz1000000">
<input type="text" id="pzdsfg1000000">
```

Comment: hum, no ... try it !

Comment: what happens if the word has more than two chars? like pzez300 ?

Comment: This was not on your original question :p, in that case use regexp I update my answer

Comment: @eawedat Check my answer. It works even if there's different word than `pz`.

Comment: @Steeve Pitis , do I have to receive event as a parameter? Couldn't I just use this.id.match('[0-9]+')[0]; ?

Comment: Sure you can since you are using Jquery. I just don't use it, that's why ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('[id^=pz]').change(function() {

console.log($(this).attr("id").split("pz")[1])

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pz1">
<input type="text" id="pz2">
<input type="text" id="pz100">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('[id^=pz]').change(function() {

  
  // Getting the numbers after the letters "pz":
  console.log(this.id.replace("pz", ""));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pz1">
<input type="text" id="pz2">
<input type="text" id="pz100">
```

Comment: Sorry! stupid mistake I thought I was editing the question!

Answer (score 1):

`On changeing` the input you have to use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all the elements first.Then use `forEach` to get the value of `id` for each element and `match` the require numbers using `regular expression`.

```js
    $('[id^=pz]').change(function() {
    var pz = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pz]');
    values = [];
    pz.forEach(function(pz){
    values.push(pz.getAttribute('id'));
    })
    values.forEach(function(value){
    console.log(value.match(/(?!pz)\d+/g)[0]);
    });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="pz1">
    <input type="text" id="pz2">
    <input type="text" id="pz100">
```

Comment: Why mix jQuery and DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a better solution to have the id as a data attribute so you do not need to rip it out of the id.

```js
$("[data-pz]").on("change", function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    console.log(elem.data("pz"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-pz="1"/>
<input data-pz="10"/>
<input data-pz="100"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, like this:

```
$.each($('[id^=pz]'), function (_, item) {
  var match = item.id.match(/pz(\d+)/);
  if(match) {
    console.log(match[1]);  
  }
});
```